# Laravel 5.5. using authentication and Ardent

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ardent

I'm having trouble using [Ardent package](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelbook/ardent) with Laravel authentication.

The problem is that in order to use Laravel authentication I have to extend my `User` model with `Authenticatable` (`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`)

But in order to use Ardent, I need to extend my `User` model with `Ardent`.

PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance (thank god), so now I am out of ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: use a php  trait

Comment: could you be a little more specific?

Comment: why do you need multiple inheritance ?

Comment: @Norgul did you read Ardent's documentation?, the Ardent class is a substitute for the Model class

Comment: Because I'd have to extend both `Ardent` and `Authenticable`

Comment: But did you read what I need? I know Ardent is a Model substitution, but I need `User extends Authenticable` if I'm going to use Laravel authentication

Comment: Authenticatable is an interface, so you must implement it and not extend it, have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authenticatable is an interface. So, you can create User extending Arden and implementing Authenticatable.

You can only extend one class but implement multiple interfaces:

```
class User extends Arden implements Authenticatable { ... }
```